# How to run maven build when launching Intellji-Idea JUnit test configuration?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

When running JUnit configuration, assertion below failed.

```
String dirName = System.getProperty("dataDir");
Assert.assertNull(dirName);
```

Parameter dataDir described in pom.xml

```
<systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>dataDir</name>
                        <value>src/main/resources/data</value>
                    </property>
</systemProperties>
```

Answer (score 0):

System properties construction was deprecated for maven-surefire-plugin
http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html

The right way to add properties is

```
<systemPropertyVariables>
                <propertyName>propertyValue</propertyName>
                <buildDirectory>${project.build.directory}</buildDirectory>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19</version>
    <configuration>
      <systemPropertyVariables>
        <propertyName>dataDir</propertyName>
        <buildDirectory>src/main/resources/data</buildDirectory>
       </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

also if you need to copy libraries you can do it this way

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/project/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```